# how to insert values into middle of array

Tags: c++

So I have an array something like this `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` the max for this array is 15 values. What I want to do is insert an int if i call a numbers index. So say I call 5 which is index 4 from there everything shifts over and the new value is inserted `[,1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7,8,9]` How would I go about this?

I tried this but i can't seem to get it right it overrides the value.
int xxx;

```
        cin >> num;
        if (num >= 0 && num <= 15) {
            for (int i = num; i < MAX; i++) {
                values[i] = values[i+1];
                cout << values[i+1] << endl;
            }
            viewVal(values, position);
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of an array and you can trivially do that with `insert`.

Comment: @us2012 i'm working out of a book so i have to follow what it says. i wish i could do this way :(

Comment: Why do you have to follow what the book says? us2012's comment is what you should do when writing software.

Comment: @dornhege i would like too but its for a class and its not what we are learning

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `values[i] = values[i+1];` shifts a value one step to the left (index 4 now has the value of index 6), but you want to shift all values one step to the right. Thus, you have to reverse the assignment.

This creates the problem that once you have moved a value to the right, the previous value on the position to the right is lost. To prevent this, you can start from the back of the array.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: I have intentionally not shown any code, because apparently you are trying to learn C++. Giving you the code would not help. You could start by writing a function that can shift all values one step to the right. Then you can update that function to only shift a suffix of the array. Try to implement small steps.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the size of plain arrays is not possible in C++. I can suggest use `std::list`, it supports constant time insertion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    auto it = std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), n);

    if(it != l.end())
    {
        l.insert(it, 0);
        for(const auto& elem: l)
        {
            std::cout << elem << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No such element" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` will be faster in this case.  About the only time `std::list` is appropriate is when you need to be able to insert and erase without invalidating iterators.

Comment: @soon well if the array only has 3 values and 20 max can't i shift it and then add my new value?

Comment: @Mr.1.0, You can, of course. But if you want to add more than 17 elements, you have to increase size(reallocate memory) of array.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help, here all the elements are first shifted to the right, then the new number is inserted into array.

```
for(int i=(num-1);i<MAX;i++)
{
int temp=values[i];
values[i+1]=temp;   
}
values[num-1]=0;
```

Comment: doesn't work. inputs the index and then turns everything else to the same number

Comment: sorry about that, initial value of i was num, that was the reason it failed...i've replaced it with (num-1), this will work